# c# negative alignment formatting

Tags: c#

I want to ask about the negative alignment formatting in Console.WriteLine() method. I understand that when you write a positive value for example `Console.WriteLine("{0,5}",123)` and if the argument "spacing" is less than the alignment component that you entered it will fill it on the left side with spaces.

But I don't understand the negative alignment. For example what would `Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}",123)` do? I don't see any difference between `Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}",123)` and `Console.WriteLine("{0}",123)`. Some explaination please.

PS: an example would make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is tricky to understand using the example that you provided, because the negative alignment component adds spaces after the word (if the absolute value of the alignment is larger than the length of the word) so you might not see those spaces unless you have something that follows.

**Example:**

Consider the words (*Stack* => 5 chars and *Overflow* => 8 Chars)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,8}\n", "Stack", "Overflow"); // StackOverflow
Console.WriteLine("{0,-6}{1,8}\n", "Stack", "Overflow"); // Stack Overflow
Console.WriteLine("{0,-6}{1,9}\n", "Stack", "Overflow"); // Stack  Overflow
```

Comment: so basically the negative alignment adds white space on the right side of the word and if it's a positive it will add on the left side?

Comment: @john Yes, exactly (adding to that the length of the word condition to make that the complete description).

Answer (score 1):

You can findout more about String.Format like

```
string.Format("LEFT:  string: ->{0,-5}<- int: ->{1,-5}<-", "abc", 123);
string.Format("RIGHT: string: ->{0,5}<- int: ->{1,5}<-", "abc", 123);
```

Output:

```
LEFT:  string: ->abc  <- int: ->123  <-
RIGHT: string: ->  abc<- int: ->  123<-
```